# How to connect to laptops on different networks through java sockets

Tags: java, networking

I have two computers, one of which opens a ServerSocket connection on port 6666 and the other connects to the server computer via a wireless router, which is configured and port forwarded to the Server computer. But still, when I try to connect to my public IP on port 6666, it gives, Java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out But the code works fine when I connect the client through "localhost".

Comment: Please give any possible reasons for the error or suggest any source to get the answer

Comment: (a) A wifi base station is almost always configured as a router with its own separate network for the wifi clients. You will have to do special configuration to enable the wifi clients to see computers on the wired network. You may be claiming to have done this, but I suspect your config is not correct. Always start with the simplest possible physical network for your development and testing before complicating it. Simple, as in two Ethernet ports w/ crossover cable. (b) This is more of a network configuration question, and as such is off-topic for Stack Overflow. So I am voting to close.

Comment: Sorry I could not make out what did  you meant in your 1st point

Comment: @S.Baner - If you did not understand Basil's comment, the gist of it is that you are asking your question in the wrong place.  This is not a programming problem. If you ask your question in the right place the people there will be able to explain things to you, and suggest what to do.